# Change the summary text in ListView Yii2

Tags: listview, yii2

How to change the summary text in the `ListView` widget of the Yii2 ?

```
echo ListView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'itemView' => function($model, $key, $index, $widget){
                return $this->render('_productViewData', ['model' => model]);
       },
       'layout' => '<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
          {pager}{summary}</div><div class="row">{items}</div><div 
          class="row"><div class="col-md-12">{pager}{summary}</div></div>',
       pager' => [
            'maxButtonCount' => 3,
            'options' => ['class' => 'pagination']
       ]
   ]);
```

If I add `"summary" => "My new text"` than my whole summary line is change to `My new text` ( the counting disapears). What I am trying to achieve is `Showing 1-19 of 19 items` to get `My new text 1-19 of 19 items`. Red some articles on github but couldn't realize how to make it happen. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just take a look at the [comment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$summary-detail) for this property you will see this:

> The following tokens will be replaced with the corresponding values:
>
> - `{begin}`: the starting row number (1-based) currently being displayed - `{end}`: the ending row number (1-based) currently being displayed
> - `{count}`: the number of rows currently being displayed
> - `{totalCount}`: the total number of rows available
> - `{page}`: the page number (1-based) current being displayed
> - `{pageCount}`: the number of pages available

So these are the replacements you can use.

Comment: So, the way I have to use those tokens is `"summary" => ["begin"=>"bla bla"]`. Did I understand it right ?

Comment: But nothing happens in my case :/ What shows now is just `{begin}`. Maybe I declare the tokens wrong ?

Comment: No, it's something like `'summary' => 'Total number is {totalCount}'` - placeholder will be replaced with value automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Youn should just  replace layout  eg:

```
'layout' => '<div>My New Text {summary}</div>',
```